# Rewriting MS stack: jQuery/C#/SQL Server

Tags: python, .net, ruby, node.js, go

I was tasked with re-writing a project that's build with jQuery (front-end), C#.NET (backend) and MS SQL Server (data storage).

I wanted to re-write in Go or Python/Django. What is a satisfactory data store to go with this? Note: It needs to be relational as there are monetary transactions involved.

Thanks

Comment: Consider asking this question on the [Go mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts/) as such a question won't be off-topic there and you might be given direct pointers. Also my take is that Go will be easier to work with after having experience with C# as the other PLs you referred to feature weak typing. And after all, well, those Go devs got the language just right -- to me, it was a breeze of fresh air. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Either MySQL or PostGres will work just fine. I personally find MySQL to be more accessible if you're new to both storage engines, however they both will serve you well given the scope of the project you've described.

You will most likely get a different answer from most people you ask, however do know that they are functionally the same for any reasonable application where you are not specifically trying to leverage the performance of minute inner workings of the engines.

Whatever route you choose, I *highly* recommend using a datastore that supports transactions ( i.e. `BEGIN... COMMIT... ROLLBACK...` ) to ensure your reads and writes happen as you expect them to, and the data comes back out the way it looked going in. PostGres supports this by default I believe, while with MySQL, you'll want to specifically [use the INNODB engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-innodb-tables.html):

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    a INT, 
    b CHAR (20), 
    INDEX (a)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `customers`(`a`,`b`) VALUES(...)
COMMIT;
```